# TypeError: time_stretch() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: audio, librosa, data-augmentation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5DyQ.png)

```
def stretch(data, rate=0.8):
    return librosa.effects.time_stretch(data, rate)

x = stretch(data)
plt.figure(figsize=(14,4))
librosa.display.waveplot(y=x, sr=sample_rate)
Audio(x, rate=sample_rate)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DzCV.png)

Above is my function and error when I tried to run it

I tried passing the data and rate into the stretch function but returns the error as shown. As you can see, it should take the data and rate then return the stretched file

Comment: Please [edit] to post also the error as text, not image.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you need set implicit rate parameter , because the definition of function has additional parameter, then parameter rate

> def time_stretch(y: np.ndarray, *, rate: float, **kwargs: Any) ->
> np.ndarray:

```
def stretch(data, rate=0.8):
    return librosa.effects.time_stretch(data, rate=rate)
```